# Sources on how to make one's wife happy

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, marriage

Are there any seforim or sources how a man can make his wife happy outside the bedroom and especially inside?

Comment: Try asking her instead of us.

Comment: I know there is a gemara in shabbos but is there anything else?

Comment: Somewhat related- shelter, clothing, and *onah* should go a long way https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92352/what-are-reasons-of-מצוות-עונה-marital-sex/92360#92360

Comment: @einodmilvado You are a Chabadnik, right? Look for this in chosson class, or in the plastic-wrapped book about tashmish

Comment: @einodmilvado Eruvin 100b. Rambam's writings on marriage. And I've heard about a certain hard-to-find sefer by Yaakov Emden with some really detailed advice

Comment: @SAH I think [this](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1983788112/ref=ox_sc_saved_title_4?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1) is what you are referring to. $15 on Amazon including translation.

Comment: @Alex Oh whoa..

Comment: Really looking for something to excite the wife inside the bedroom

Comment: @einodmilvado I think this post is likely not getting you what you want because it wasn't written to clearly ask for what you want. I appreciate that it's tricky to balance the need for modesty (*tzeniut*) with the need to be clear about what you're looking for. As this question has already been answered, you might want to try again, along the lines of "Are there any seforim that provide advice for pleasing one's spouse during marital relations?" ...

Comment: ... I think that a asking for such advice rather than for recommendations of seforim would probably be excessively immodest for this public forum (See the second main bullet under Notes [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)), but that asking for the seforim probably would be OK. I'd suggest including in your question post some explanation of why you expect that such seforim may exist in Jewish traditional literature.

Comment: @isaac Moses that's exactly what I am asking!

Comment: If I recall R' Aryeh Kaplan's book on marriage suggests that Judaism may have at one point had its own kama-sutra-like text that was subsequently lost. (Today you'd get thrown out of yeshiva for daring to say such a thing.)

Answer (score 7):

I found that re-reading books on marriage after being married for a few years is always inspiring and a source of new ideas. Three books I would recommend are

- [The marriage covenant](http://a.co/iWPD5iJ) by R Elyashiv Knohl (it comes with a separate small booklet on "inside the bedroom") with approbations from R Yaakov Ariel, R Aharon Lichtenstein, R Zalman Nechemia Goldberg
- [Fulfillment in marriage](http://a.co/2tbNzGX) by R Shmuel Eisenblatt (volume 1 is for men, vol. 2 for women) with approbations from R Nissim Karelitz, Chaim Scheinberg and others
- [The garden of peace](https://www.breslev.co.il/store/books/family_and_relationships/the_garden_of_peace.aspx?id=7269&language=english) by R Shalom Arush based on the teachings of R Nachman m' Breslev

All three insist on the importance of frequent and open communication with one's wife as a pillar of happiness (as suggested by DoubleAA in comments).

Comment: @einodmilvado that is what I understood and why I mention the marriage covenant which comes with a separate booklet on this topic. Now that you mention it I remember I also read [this](http://a.co/9rxJknl) on Kindle a long time ago but don't remember the book. See if the description interests you

Comment: Anything from the rishonim or famous achronim

Comment: @einodmilvado not that I know of - sorry - but you could ask a chasan teacher. See also resources here on MY: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33895/11501

Answer (score 4):

**[Pesachim 109a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=109&format=pdf)**

> ת"ר חייב אדם לשמח בניו ובני ביתו ברגל שנא' ושמחת בחגך במה משמחם ביין
>   רבי יהודה אומר אנשים בראוי להם ונשים בראוי להן אנשים בראוי להם ביין
>   ונשים במאי תני רב יוסף בבבל בבגדי צבעונין בארץ ישראל בבגדי פשתן
>   מגוהצין
>
> Our Rabbis taught: A man is in duty bound to make his children and his
>   household rejoice on a Festival, for it is said, And thou shalt
>   rejoice it, thy feast, [thou and thy son, and thy daughter, etc.]
>   Wherewith does he make them rejoice? With wine. R. Judah said: Men
>   with what is suitable for them, and women with, what is suitable for
>   them. ‘Men with what is suitable for them’: with wine. And women with
>   what? R. Joseph recited: in Babylonia, with coloured garments; in
>   Eretz Yisrael, with ironed lined garments. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Pesachim.pdf))

[R. Mordechi Yaffe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Yoffe) cites this in his [introduction to Levush](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9222&st=&pgnum=5), and says that this is the main joy for women.

> שכן דרך נשים עיקר שמחתן היא בבגדי צבעונין כדאמרינן פרק ערבי פסחים נשים
>   במאי משמחן אמר רב יוסף בבבל בבגדי צבעונין בארץ ישראל בבגדי פשתן
>   מגוהצין

Comment: This seems to be restricted to Yom Tov - more specifically the *regalim*; not even Rosh Hashanna or Yom Kippur or Shabbat, for that matter. What about ways to make her happy on these days as well as the rest of the year? (Thank goodness for dry cleaners! Numerous men don't know how to iron clothes!)

Comment: @DanF It doesn't say that clothes only make her happy on holidays. It's just that the obligation to make her happy is on holidays. Presumably, though, the same methods can make her happy all year round.

Comment: And this answer also can be applied in the bedroom with colorful or linen pajamas.

Comment: @Alex Not suggesting this has any Torah implications at all, but I am a woman, and I am quite sure that buying clothes would not do it for me. I do like clothes and would appreciate getting some new ones around the holidays, as our tradition has suggested. But is it "the main joy for women?" --Not this one.

Comment: @SAH This is probably why Double AA suggested asking one's wife instead if sefarim.

Comment: @SAH I wonder if part of the reasoning that the Gemarah suggests clothes may have something to do with making the **husband** happy. (Remember, it's the **giving** as well as the receiving that makes people happy.)

Comment: @DanF Ah. I guess I wasn't aware that husbands enjoyed buying clothes for their wives *that* much, but it's an awfully sweet thought...

Comment: ...Maybe if it's "colorful or linen pajamas" so to speak. Is this what we are getting at?

Answer (score 0):

Ask her what she likes in the bedroom and what she likes outside of it.

Source: Life

Note: Some people don't always know what will make them happier and what won't.... But you should always start with talking to the person first, especially if you are married to them.

Comment: I know this was phrased as a joke, but I think this was phrased perfectly for the question. I don’t think this should be deleted at all.

Comment: So on other words your saying there is nothing?

Comment: @einodmilvado I'm not saying that. But I'm saying that maybe the first person you should ask is your wife.

Comment: Is this an answer to "how a man can make his wife happy outside the bedroom and especially inside" or only to part of that? If it's an answer to part, you should indicate as much in the post; if it's an answer to the whole, then you should indicate how, as it's unclear to at least this reader.